# Writing Unit tests for Continuation tasks in .Net

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, task

I am new to Unit testing and trying to write unit tests for a WPF ViewModel that uses tasks. I have a method in VM that is wired up to a Button in WPF. Below code summarizes what I am trying to do.
    class MainPageViewModel
    {
        private IService service_;

```
    public void StartTask()
    {
        var task = service_.StartServiceAsync();
        task.ContinueWith(AfterService);
    }

    private void AfterService(Task<IResult> result)
    {
        //update UI with result
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public Test_StartTask()
    {
        MainPageViewModel vm = new MainPageViewModel();
        vm.StartTask();
        //need to check if UI is updated but since the AfterService is called on a different thread the assert fails

    }
}
```

In my Test Method I can't write Assert after the StartTask() call, please help me on how to handle such scenarios? TIA.

Comment: What you really trying to test. By looking at the code, i cannot see any important behavior your trying to Unit Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a synchronization primitive to wait on.  If you don't want this around in production builds, you could guard it with an `#if _DEBUG` or `#if UNIT_TEST` (where `UNIT_TEST` is defined for a test-specific build configuration).

```
class MainPageViewModel
{
    private IService service_;
    public AutoResetEvent UpdateEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public void StartTask()
    {
        var task = service_.StartServiceAsync();
        task.ContinueWith(AfterService);
    }

    private void AfterService(Task<IResult> result)
    {
        //update UI with result
        UpdateEvent.Set();
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public Test_StartTask()
    {
        MainPageViewModel vm = new MainPageViewModel();
        vm.StartTask();
        if( vm.UpdateEvent.WaitOne(5000) ) {
           // check GUI state
        } else {
           throw new Exception("task didn't complete");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can surely use this technique, but just want to check if there is any more elegant way of doing this or if there is something wrong with my design before resorting to this. Isn't using Event based async pattern better for writing code that can be better unit tested rather than the TPL async?